# Tensorflow Serving using Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, serving

I have created a Neural Network Regression Model and I wish to deploy it using AWS. 
I am using tensorflow serving, and have gone so far as to save the model.

Now I am trying to use Docker to deploy it in the container using Docker on Windows 10 home
As an example, I tried to use multiple tutorials but when it comes to this command, no matter what I do, it just doesn't work for me:

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" -e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two tensorflow/serving
```

Every time I change something, I get a different error. I am totally at loss. Please direct me to some tutorials for this that are simple but complete for novices like me. I have already read the TensorFlow documentation but the errors persist. 
Any help would REALLY oblige me greatly since I have been stuck for about a month now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest tutorial I found was https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker#serving_example

Also

`Docker toolkit`
has trouble with the mounts as you have to manually specify the path, so if you can afford it, upgrade to `Windows Pro` which will simplify dockerization. That way you will get `Docker Desktop` which is much simpler.